# Range $[n,2n]$ containing smallest positive integer $x$ such that $x^x$ contains digits $2016$ in a row

Tags: probability, number-theory, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

How do I find a range $[n, 2n]$ such that it contains the smallest positive integer $x$ such that $x^x$ contains the digits $2016$ in a row (consecutively), up to sufficiently high probability? I asked my older brother and one of his math postdoc friends, and they had no clue, so I figured this would be fair game here.

**Edit:** No computer program here please, I would like to some "by hand" insights.

Comment: Let $f(n)$ be the cumulative number of digits in the first $n$ values of $x^x$, we roughly guess there is a $(1-1/10^4)^{f(n)}$ chance that the value is contained. 

Lets pick a value such that the chance is $.2$ and see what happens with two times that value.

we get $f(x) = 2231$ which seems to be $x=53$ which gives $f(53)= 2195$, so we would sort of expect that there's a chance under $20\%$ that the number is larger than $n$.

On the other hand $f(106)$ is $10325$ so you get like a $45\%$ chance it works.

Comment: It's somewhat weird to speak of "probability" here, as the number $x$ is a single fixed value.

Comment: I think the only way is to let a program try increasing values of x until the answer is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the probability that $x^x$ contains the digit sequence 2016. Let f(n) be the number of digits in $x^x$, which is about $f(n) = x \cdot \log_{10}(x)$, then the probability is about $0.9999^{f(x)-3}$.

The expected number of values x ≤ N where $x^x$ contains the digits 2016 is very roughly $0.0001 N^2 \log_{10}(N/2)/ 2$. So we should find the smallest x by checking say 200 values x, no problem with the right software.

If you don't have any software that can find the smallest x, you can estimate the probability that [N, 2N] contains the smallest x: Let p(N) be the probability that $x^x$ contains 2016 for some x ≤ N; this can be calculated from the expected number of x's. And then we just need p(2N) - p(N-1) and find for which N it is largest.